# Why don't we always use FTS tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

The wording of my question comes from a comment at the end of the blog post [Android Quick Tip: Using SQLite FTS Tables](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/). As the title implies, the post tells how to create and query full text search virual tables in your android app. The comment by user [Fer Raviola](https://disqus.com/by/ferraviola/) specifically reads

> my question is why dont' we ALWAYS use FTS tables!. I mean, they ARE
>   faster

The blog author did not reply (at the time of this writing anyway), but I thought it was an interesting question that deserves an answer. After all, FTS tables can be made for an entire table, not just a specific text column. At first look, it seems like it would both simply and speed up queries.

One could also completely do away with the non-virtual table. That would eliminate having to keep the virtual and non-virtual tables in sync with [triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) and [external content tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2_2). All the data would be stored in the virtual table.

[@CL. says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101166/3681880) that this is not a good option, though, because "FTS tables cannot be efficiently queried for non-FTS searches." I assume that this has something to do with what the [SQLite documentation says here](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_4):

```
-- The examples in this block assume the following FTS table:
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mail USING fts3(subject, body);

SELECT * FROM mail WHERE rowid = 15;                -- Fast. Rowid lookup.
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE body MATCH 'sqlite';       -- Fast. Full-text query.
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE mail MATCH 'search';       -- Fast. Full-text query.
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE rowid BETWEEN 15 AND 20;   -- Slow. Linear scan.
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE subject = 'database';      -- Slow. Linear scan.
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE subject MATCH 'database';  -- Fast. Full-text query.
```

But are the slow queries really so much slower than if one were just doing a normal query on a normal table? If so, why?

Here are some general potential downsides that I can think of to only using a virtual FTS table in Android:

- The table would be larger because of the size that the index takes.
- Operations like INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE would be slower because the index would have to be updated.

But as far as queries themselves go, I don't see what the problem would be.

**Update**

The Android documentation example [Storing and Searching for Data](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html) uses only an FTS virtual table in its database. This seems to confirm that there are at least some viable options for FTS only databases.

Answer (score 4):

When the table is small, scanning all rows does not take much time.
For large tables, however, this can take a very long time. (The speed would be similar to a normal, unindexed table.)

Comment: So, would an FTS only database be a viable option in some cases?

Comment: It would be possible to imagine such a case.

Comment: But in your opinion this would not be the way to go in the majority of cases, is that correct?

Comment: For very small tables, you probably wouldn't have needed FTS in the first place.